# Why fluentWait() is slow?

Tags: java, selenium

I'm using the `fluentWait()` on my `selenium` code. But I noticed that although the element need waited has been loaded on the browser, it is still waiting for a while. It wastes a lot of time, but I don't know the reason. Does anyone knows why is it?

Comment: How can we tell if you don't post the code you are using and describe the scenario.

Comment: Is there some reason you aren't using `WebDriverWait`? Why do you need to use `FluentWait`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each FluentWait instance defines the maximum amount of time to wait for a condition, as well as the frequency with which to check the condition. Furthermore, the user may configure the wait to ignore specific types of exceptions whilst waiting, such as NoSuchElementExceptions when searching for an element on the page.

```
  // Waiting 30 seconds for an element to be present on the page, checking
  // for its presence once every 5 seconds.

  Wait wait = new FluentWait(driver)
    .withTimeout(30, SECONDS)
    .pollingEvery(5, SECONDS)
    .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
```

Will be slower as:

```
  // Waiting 30 seconds for an element to be present on the page, checking
  // for its presence once every 1 second.

  Wait wait = new FluentWait(driver)
    .withTimeout(30, SECONDS)
    .pollingEvery(1, SECONDS)
    .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
```

So, it depends on you what you will use.

Comment: Thanks, I change the 5 to 1, now it more quickly

Comment: By the way, for some reason, if I only use fluentWait(By.id(xxxx)), it will target on other elements, so I need target it's parent element first. How can I do?